# Remove duplicate unordered tuples from list

Tags: python, list, tuples, python-itertools

In a list of tuples, I want to have just one copy of a tuple where it may be (x, y) or (y, x).

So, in:

```
# pairs = list(itertools.product(range(3), range(3)))
pairs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

the result should be:

```
result = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)] # updated pairs
```

This list of tuples is generated using [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) but I want to remove the duplicates.

*My working solution:*

```
pairs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

result = []
for pair in pairs:
    a, b = pair
    # reordering in increasing order
    temp = (a, b) if a < b else (b, a)
    result.append(temp)
print(list(set(result))) # I could use sorted() but the order doesn't matter
```

**How can this be improved?**

Comment: What is wrong with your solution? What aspect of your code are you looking to improve?

Comment: @ChrisMartin speed improvements > in-place removals > concise code

Comment: @AjitZero, these look like coordinates. Is that where they originate? The reason I ask is that sparse matrices are good at storing and manipulating such data. I've included a solution below which takes advantage of this.

Comment: @jp_data_analysis For my case, no. Thanks for sharing that though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [combinations_with_replacement](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement)

> The code for combinations_with_replacement() can be also expressed as a subsequence of product() after filtering entries where the elements are not in sorted order (according to their position in the input pool)

```
import itertools
pairs = list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(range(3), 2))
print(pairs)

>>> [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**edit** I just realized, your solution matches my solution. What you are doing is just fine. If you need to do this for a very large list, then there are some other options you may want to look into, like a key value store.

If you need to remove dupes more programatically, then you can use a function like this:

```
def set_reduce(pairs):
    new_pairs = set([])
    for x,y in pairs:
        if x < y:
            new_pairs.add((x,y))
        else:
            new_pairs.add((y,x))
    return new_pairs
```

running this results in

```
>>>set_reduce(pairs)
set([(0, 1), (1, 2), (0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (1, 1)])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution which relies on [sparse matrices](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix). This works for the following reasons:

An entry in a matrix cannot contain two values. Therefore, uniqueness is guaranteed.

Selecting the upper triangle ensures that (0, 1) is preferred above (1, 0), and inclusion of both is not possible.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix, triu

lst = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1),
       (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]

# get row coords & col coords
d1, d2 = list(zip(*lst))

# set up sparse matrix inputs
row, col, data = np.array(d1), np.array(d2), np.array([1]*len(lst))

# get upper triangle of matrix including diagonal
m = triu(csr_matrix((data, (row, col))), 0)

# output coordinates
result = list(zip(*(m.row, m.col)))

# [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 2)]
```